# document.getElementById for variable Elemnts in jQuery

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, getelementbyid

First of all Hello guys, 
ur community is awesome i often found here the perfect solution for my Problems.
But now i seemed to have a problem wich might be new here (i can't find anaywher s olution)
is have a jQuery-plugin witch gets 4 variables witch Geocoords as Value (50.3675658° or -23.73456°) in an Object i call my funktion with `$('#map').rectangle(qsparam);`

'#map' is the ID of the div, in wich Google-maps gives me my custom-map with a border around the 2 Points i gave in the object.

This is my Plugin:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.rectangle = function(param) {
        var map, rectangle, coords = param || {};
        var southwest = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.s || -10, coords.w || -10);
        var northeast = new google.maps.LatLng(coords.n || 10, coords.e || 10);
        return this.each(function() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                'mapTypeId' : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
            })
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast);
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            rectangle = new google.maps.Rectangle({
                map : map,
                strokeColor : "#008DCF",
                strokeOpacity : 0.6,
                strokeWeight : 4,
                fillColor : "#B8B23B",
                fillOpacity : 0.18,
                Bounds : bounds
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

but i want to keep the Plugin varaible for other div's, so can u plaese help me to change the document.getElementById('map') into something like document.getElementById(*name of the div i don't know atm*), so that i don't need to change ma Plugin when i want to use it for div's with other names?

Greetz ur Basti890

Comment: Add a parameter to your plugin's function with the name of the div used for the map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `this` instead of `document.getElementById('map')`.

```
return this.each(function() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(this, {'mapTypeId' : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN});
    // ...
```

Comment: LOL i think this was to easy it works 'uff finaly'.

Thank you very much <3